# lxml xpath - Can't find body tag

Tags: html, xpath, tags, find, lxml

I'm trying to write a plugin in Calibre that checks for footnotes in an epub doc (basically looking for font-size < a certain value).
I need to get all the child tags in a html file (inside the `<body>` tag) that contain text but I've come across a problem.

LXML xpath won't find the `<body>` or anything in it.

Below is the html which has been created from Calibre's own functions and an inserted `<p>Hello World</p>` using `etree.SubElement`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Hero filtered</title>
  <link href="page_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello World</p></body>
</html>
```

These are the things I've tried

```
query = ".//body" # This doesn't 
query = "body" # This doesn't 
query = ".//*/body" # This doesn't 
query = ".//*//body" # This doesn't
query = "./body" # This doesn't 
query = ".//body/*" # This doesn't 
query = ".//body/p" # This doesn't
```

These do work though

```
query = "/*/*[2]/*[normalize-space(text())]" # this works
found= self.footnotes_file.find("{*}" + "body") # this works
```

I've been using the following function from lxml

```
found = self.footnotes_file.xpath(query)
```

where self.footnotes_file is generated with the Calibre function `parsed(self, name)` which returns the root element of the html file passed to it

```
self.footnotes_file = current_container().parsed(footnote_file_name)
```

So the question is what am I doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into problems with namespaces, it seems. There are a few ways to handle it. 
Two simple ones would be to delete the namespaces reference from

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

so that the tag is just `<html>`.

Another is to change your query to

```
//*[local-name()="body"]
```

and see if these work.

Comment: Thanks Jack, perfect answer. I went with the second option as Calibre creates the html template and it seemed like too much of a hack to keep deleting the xmlns attribute. Just out of interest is there a way to create the xpath query with the namespace?

Comment: @Rob Yes. But to make it (barely) manageable, you'll have to create a prefix (sort of a shortcut) for the namespace. In your case, for example, you could use `('//x:body', namespaces = {'x':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})`, with `x` being anything. I, personally, would stick to using `local-name()`.

Comment: I absolutely agree. Thanks for your help